# Не переключается на попапы внутри попапа. То есть не закрывется предыдущий попап

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть кнопка внутри попапа, при нажатии на которую открывается другой попап, в котором есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую открывается предыдущий попап и так по кругу. Но при нажатии желаемого эффекта нет, окно то появляеться новое, вот только предыдущее **не закрывается**, что может быть причиной такого поведения, подскажите, пожалуйста.

```js
const navProfile = document.querySelector('.header__profile__list')
const imgProfileBtn = document.querySelector('.header__profile__img')

imgProfileBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation()
  if (event.currentTarget === imgProfileBtn) {
    navProfile.classList.toggle('header__profile__list-active')
  }
  burger.classList.remove('active');
  nav.classList.remove('active');
})

body.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (!event.target.closest('.header__profile__list')) {
    closeAuthMenu()
  }
});

const popupLinkLogin = document.querySelectorAll('.popup__link-login')
const popupLinkRegister = document.querySelectorAll('.popup__link-register')
// const lockPadding = document.querySelectorAll('.lock-padding')

let unlock = true

if (popupLinkLogin.length > 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < popupLinkLogin.length; i++) {
    const elements = popupLinkLogin[i]
    elements.addEventListener(('click'), (e) => {
      const popupWindowLogin = document.querySelector('.popup__login')
      popupOpenLogin(popupWindowLogin);
      closeAuthMenu()
      e.preventDefault()
    })
  }
}

if (popupLinkRegister.length > 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < popupLinkRegister.length; i++) {
    const elements = popupLinkRegister[i]
    elements.addEventListener(('click'), (e) => {
      const popupWindowRegister = document.querySelector('.popup__register')
      popupOpenRegister(popupWindowRegister);
      closeAuthMenu()
      e.preventDefault()
    })
  }
}

const popupCloseIcon = document.querySelectorAll('.popup__close')
if (popupCloseIcon.length > 0) {
  popupCloseIcon.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener(('click'), (e) => {
      popupClose(el.closest('.modal'))
      e.preventDefault()
    })
  })
}

function popupOpenLogin(currentPopupLogin) {
  if (currentPopupLogin && unlock) {
    const popupActive = document.querySelector('.popup__login.open')
    if (popupActive) {
      popupClose(popupActive, false)
    } else {
      bodyLock()
    }
    currentPopupLogin.classList.add('open')
    currentPopupLogin.addEventListener(('click'), (e) => {
      if (!e.target.closest('.popup__content')) {
        popupClose(e.target.closest('.modal'))
      }
    })
  }
}

function popupOpenRegister(currentPopupRegister) {
  if (currentPopupRegister && unlock) {
    const popupActive = document.querySelector('.popup__register.open')
    if (popupActive) {
      popupClose(popupActive, false)
    } else {
      bodyLock()
    }
    currentPopupRegister.classList.add('open')
    currentPopupRegister.addEventListener(('click'), (e) => {
      if (!e.target.closest('.popup__content')) {
        popupClose(e.target.closest('.modal'))
      }
    })
  }
}

function popupClose(popupActive, doUnlock = true) {
  if (unlock) {
    popupActive.classList.remove('open')
    if (doUnlock) {
      bodyUnlock()
    }
  }
}

function bodyLock() {
  // const  lockPaddingValue = window.innerWidth - document.querySelector('.wrapper').offsetWidth + 'px'
  // // for (let i = 0; i < lockPadding.length; i++) {
  // //     const el = lockPadding[i];
  // //     el.style.paddingRight = lockPaddingValue
  // // }
  // body.style.paddingRight = lockPaddingValue
  body.classList.add('lock')

  unlock = false
  setTimeout(function() {
    unlock = true
  }, 600)
}

function bodyUnlock() {
  // setTimeout( function () {
  // for (let i = 0; i < lockPadding.length; i++) {
  //     const el = lockPadding[i];
  //     el.style.paddingRight = '0px'
  //     }
  body.classList.remove('lock')
  // }, 600)
}
```

```css
.header__profile__list {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 70px;
  background-color: var(--fourth-color);
  padding: 5px 12.5px 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, visibility 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.header__profile__list-active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.header__profile__list-text {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  line-height: 20px;
  /* 133.333% */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.header__profile__list-text::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -5px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: var(--third-color);
}

.header__profile__list-item {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.header__profile__list-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.header__profile__list-register,
.header__profile__list-login {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: var(--body-font);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color .3s;
}

.header__profile__list-login:hover,
.header__profile__list-register:hover {
  color: var(--third-color);
  transition: color .3s;
}

.header__profile__img {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease
}

.header__profile__img img:hover {
  fill: var(--third-color);
}

.header__img svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header__img svg:hover path {
  fill: var(--third-color);
}

.popup__login,
.popup__register {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
}

.popup__login.open,
.popup__register.open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.popup__login.open .popup__content,
.popup__register.open .popup__content {
  transform: translate(0px, 0%);
  opacity: 1;
}

// .popup__login.open .
// .popup__register.open
.popup__body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 35px 15px;
}

.popup__content {
  background-color: var(--fourth-color);
  // color: var(--second-color);
  padding: 20px 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 262px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
  transform: translate(0px, - 100%);
}

.popup__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffff;
}

.popup__close>svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.popup__close svg path {
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.popup__close svg:hover path {
  fill: var(--third-color);
  stroke: var(--third-color);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.popup__title {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: var(--second-font);
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 20px;
  /* 100% */
  letter-spacing: 0.025rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.popup__form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.popup__label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.popup__label>span {
  font-size: 1.066rem;
  line-height: 20px;
  /* 133.333% */
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.popup__label-input-name,
.popup__label-input-password {
  border: none;
  outline: 1px solid var(--third-color);
  color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  font-size: 100%;
}

.popup__login-btn {
  background-color: var(--fourth-color);
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: 1px solid #0C0C0E;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  max-width: max-content;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s;
  margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.popup__login-btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--third-color);
  transition: all .3s;
  outline: none;
}

.popup__text-login-register {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16);
  font-size: 0.625rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.popup__login-register {
  font-size: 0.625rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  background-color: var(--fourth-color);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color .3s;
}

.popup__login-register:hover {
  color: var(--third-color);
  transition: color .3s;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 2px solid var(--third-color);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(229, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

input {
  transition: outline-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.popup__login,
.popup__register {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
}

.popup__login.open,
.popup__register.open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.popup__login.open .popup__content,
.popup__register.open .popup__content {
  transform: translate(0px, 0%);
  opacity: 1;
}

// .popup__login.open .
// .popup__register.open
.popup__body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 35px 15px;
}

.popup__content {
  background-color: var(--fourth-color);
  // color: var(--second-color);
  padding: 20px 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 262px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
  transform: translate(0px, - 100%);
}

.popup__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffff;
}

.popup__close>svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.popup__close svg path {
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.popup__close svg:hover path {
  fill: var(--third-color);
  stroke: var(--third-color);
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.popup__title {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: var(--second-font);
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 20px;
  /* 100% */
  letter-spacing: 0.025rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.popup__form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.popup__label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.popup__label>span {
  font-size: 1.066rem;
  line-height: 20px;
  /* 133.333% */
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.popup__label-input-name,
.popup__label-input-password {
  border: none;
  outline: 1px solid var(--third-color);
  color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
  font-size: 100%;
}

.popup__login-btn {
  background-color: var(--fourth-color);
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: 1px solid #0C0C0E;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  max-width: max-content;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s;
  margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}

.popup__login-btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--third-color);
  transition: all .3s;
  outline: none;
}

.popup__text-login-register {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16);
  font-size: 0.625rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.popup__login-register {
  font-size: 0.625rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  background-color: var(--fourth-color);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color .3s;
}

.popup__login-register:hover {
  color: var(--third-color);
  transition: color .3s;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 2px solid var(--third-color);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(229, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

input {
  transition: outline-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header__profile__list">
  <b class="header__profile__list-text">Profile</b>
  <li class="header__profile__list-item"> <button class="header__profile__list-login popup__link-login">Log In</button></li>
  <li class="header__profile__list-item"> <button class="header__profile__list-register popup__link-register">Register</button></li>
</ul>


<div class="popup__login modal">
  <div class="popup__body">
    <div class="popup__content">
      <button class="popup__close">
        <svg width="19" height="19" viewBox="0 0 19 19" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M2 16.8507L17 2.00003" stroke="#0C0C0E" stroke-width="3"/>
            <path d="M2 2.14926L17 17" stroke="#0C0C0E" stroke-width="3"/>
        </svg>    
      </button>
      <div class="popup__title">
        Login
      </div>
      <form class="popup__form">
        <label class="popup__label">
            <span>
                E-mail or readers card
            </span>
            <input class="popup__label-input-name" type="text">
        </label>
        <label class="popup__label">
            <span>
                Password
            </span>
            <input class="popup__label-input-password" type="password">
        </label>
        <button class="popup__login-btn" type="submit">Log In</button>
      </form>
      <span class="popup__text-login-register">
          Don’t have an account?
          <button class="popup__login-register popup__link-register"> Register</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="popup__register modal">
  <div class="popup__body">
    <div class="popup__content">
      <button class="popup__close">
          <svg width="19" height="19" viewBox="0 0 19 19" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M2 16.8507L17 2.00003" stroke="#0C0C0E" stroke-width="3"/>
              <path d="M2 2.14926L17 17" stroke="#0C0C0E" stroke-width="3"/>
          </svg>    
      </button>
      <div class="popup__title">
        Register
      </div>
      <form class="popup__form">
        <label class="popup__label">
              <span>
                  First name
              </span>
              <input class="popup__label-input-name" type="text">
          </label>
        <label class="popup__label">
              <span>
                  Last name
              </span>
              <input class="popup__label-input-password" type="password">
          </label>
        <label class="popup__label">
              <span>
                  E-mail
              </span>
              <input class="popup__label-input-password" type="password">
          </label>
        <label class="popup__label">
            <span>
                Password
            </span>
            <input class="popup__label-input-password" type="password">
        </label>
        <button class="popup__login-btn" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
      </form>
      <span class="popup__text-login-register">
          Already have an account?
          <button class="popup__login-register popup__link-login">Login</button>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```